# Azure Service Bus Explorer - Required Permissions

Tags: azureservicebus

Not sure this is the correct forum for this, but I was wondering if you guys are also using the Azure Service Bus explorer to explore and troubleshoot issues in the Service Bus.

I would like to grant access to power users, but it seems the minimum access requirement is Manage and this permission allows you to delete the queues. Is there any way we can configure the explorer to require only read access ?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO...https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is "no". The tool is designed for managing namespaces and requires the Manage policy.